# Именованные кортежи - как использовать?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Разрабатываю класс `Ss`, внутри которого объявляю именованный кортеж и пытаюсь использовать объявленный тип в одном из методов. Вкратце, выглядит это так:

```
class Ss:
    classStat = collections.namedtuple("classStat", "a b c d")
    
    def getStat(self):
        ss_stat = classStat(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
```

Но ничего не получается, говорит, что

> NameError: name 'classStat' is not defined

Я вставлял объявление `classStat` в конструктор класса и выносил его на уровень всего класса, объявлял `classStat` как `global` и не объявлял, добавлял `self` и убирал...  Ничего не помогает!

Кто знает - как надо объявить `classStat` так, что бы его можно было использовать в методах класса ?

Ну и попутный вопрос - а обязательно, что бы первый параметр `collections.namedtuple` совпадал по написанию с `LValue`, написанным с другой стороны символа '=' ?

Comment: У вас похоже проблемы с классами, а не с именованными кортежами... Чтобы ответить на вопрос было бы неплохо понять назначение вашего класса - что вы хотите с этим классом делать?

Comment: @MaxU *что вы хотите с этим классом делать?* - не понял вопрос. То же, что делают с любым другим описанием класса - объявлять экземпляры переменных этого класса.  Переменные класса *Ss* предназначены для работы с абонентскими станциями (Subscriber Station), а метод *getStat* должен собирать статистику работы абонента в именованный кортеж *classStat*.

Comment: Про соответсвие имени типа (`typename`) и имени переменной, ссылающейся на этот тип - нет, их совпадение вовсе не обязательно.

Comment: такие объявления действительно правильно делать на уровне класса, как описано в задании, а не в init методе, на уровне объекта класса, как в варианте ответа. Но обращаться к нему из методов, все-равно надо или self.classStat() или Ss.classStat(). Такой паттерн, часто используется в ORM [пример](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html)/

Comment: @mkkik *совпадение вовсе не обязательно.*  Но тогда, если я напишу нечто вроде *A = collections.namedtuple("B"...)*, то как я должен объявлять переменные этого класа: *x = A()* или *x = B()* ?!

Comment: По имени ссылки: `A = collections.namedtuple("B"...); x = A()`. Ведь имени `B` не будет сушествовать в пространстве имен. `B` - это имя/название типа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас класс без конструктора получился (нужно добавить метод `__init__`) - в нём вы можете обозначить атрибут-кортеж. Метод `getStat` можно модифицировать, чтобы он мог принимать параметры, если это потребуется:

```
import collections

class Ss:
    def __init__(self):
        self.classStat = collections.namedtuple("classStat", "a b c d")

    def getStat(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):
        return self.classStat(a, b, c, d)

q = Ss()
print(q.getStat())
print(q.getStat(10, 11, 12, 13))
print(q.getStat(10, 11, 12, 13).b)
# classStat(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
# classStat(a=10, b=11, c=12, d=13)
# 11
```

Если вы хотите чтобы атрибут `classStat` выступал не только как шаблон, но и присваивал значение из метода:

```
import collections

class Ss:
    def __init__(self):
        self.classStat = collections.namedtuple("classStat", "a b c d")

    def getStat(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):
        self.classStat = self.classStat(a, b, c, d)

q = Ss()
q.getStat(10, 11, 12, 13)
print q.classStat.b
# 11
```

По поводу использования именованных кортежей. Вы объявляете экземпляр кортежа, далее вы его можете использовать сколько потребуется раз:

```
import collections

A = collections.namedtuple("dog", "age owner")
tobik = A(1, "Jon")
lucky = A(2, "Grace")
print(tobik.age)
print(lucky.owner)
# 1
# Grace

B = collections.namedtuple("cat", "name age owner")
data_list = [["Barsik", 3, "Mike"], ["Fillip", 2, "Rachel"]]
tuple_list = [B(*x) for x in data_list]
for c in tuple_list:
    print(c.name, c.age, c.owner)
# ('Barsik', 3, 'Mike')
# ('Fillip', 2, 'Rachel')
```

Comment: Класс у меня с конструктором и изначально я создавал класс кортежа именно внутри конструктора. Но, видимо, что-то не дописал - не прокатило. Вот и начал пробовать разные варианты.  Но сейчас - реально работает.

Comment: А по второму моему вопросу может что-то сказать? А то я не очень понимаю, в чём там разница между первым параметром и LValue.

Comment: не вижу чего-то LValue... добавьте пример мб, а так имена в кортеже могут быть заданы любые

Comment: Проблема ТС не в отсутствии конструктора, а в использовании области видимости. Наличие или отсутсвие конструктора тут не важно.

Comment: @Eugene Dennis  *добавьте пример*:  если я напишу нечто вроде *A = collections.namedtuple("B"...)*, то как я должен объявлять переменные этого класа: *x = A()* или *x = B()*

Comment: добавил примеров использования именованных кортежей